# if statement inside formular1c1 and error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automatically fill a range with formulaR1C1 and a `= IF()` i recorded before, but I keep getting a 1004 error.
I have this loop running several time in this particular sub, and it works well for every other formula, but with the  `= IF()` it doesn't work...

The line `rcell1.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0;RC[-1];0)"`is highlighted.

```
Set subgain = Range(Cells(i - period - 1, 16), Cells(i + j, 16))
With subgain
For Each rcell1 In subgain
       rcell1.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0;RC[-1];0)"
Next rcell1
End With
```

Any idea pliz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your formula, you're using `;` as delimiter but it should be instead `,`. Replace this:

```
rcell1.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0;RC[-1];0)
```

with this:

```
rcell1.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0,RC[-1],0)"
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a programmer and I struggled with adding an if statement using quotes. lColName.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF([@Element] <> "",1,0)". I also was getting error 1004 pointing the formula

I needed to add the if Formula to a table column.

Came up with this solution with the help of this tread, I needed double quotes ... Thanks for the great help!

Hopefully this can help someone else

```
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim lCol As ListColumn

Range("K9").Select

  For intfourth = RGE1_ComboBox.Text To RGE2_ComboBox.Text
  
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set lColName = lo.ListColumns(10)
    lColName.DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF([@Element] <> """",1,0)"

    Next intfourth
```